# Synchronously dynamically import Type at runtime

Tags: typescript

I've reviewed the topics here on StackOverflow and they all either use await (`const m = await import(filename)`) or utilize their imported module at the same time they import it: (`import(filename).then((x)=> { /* work with x */ })`)

In my case I'm trying to convert a factory method that returns an implementation of an interface based on a supplied parameter. I want to refactor my code to not statically import the implementation modules/classes and instead import the single requested implementation at runtime.

This is what I have now:

```
import { AcmeWidgetProvider } from './AcmeWidgetProvider'
import { IWidgetProvider } from './Types'

export class WidgetFactory {
  static Create (id: string): IWidgetProvider {

    switch(id) {
      case '230314b2-7863-4764-adbd-91969fedc44a': return new AcmeWidgetProvider(id)
      default: `Unable to resolve provider for ID ${id}`
    }
  }
}
```

To something like:

```
import { IWidgetProvider } from './Types'

export class WidgetFactory {
  static Create (filename: string): IWidgetProvider {
    return import(filename) as IWidgetProvider
  }
}
```

`Create` needs to be synchronous and return an instance of the class exported from the module specified by parameter `filename`. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to accomplish this. A regular import statement imports Types that you can then instantiate with `new`, etc.
I'm stumped/stuck on how to achieve what I want.